# Соседний селектор

Tags: css

Структура документа следующая

```
 div.begin
    div.p
    div.p
    div.p
    div.p //Последний
    div.end
```

CSS файл

```
div.p {
    bgcolor: #xxx;
}
div.p: hover {
    bgcolor: #yyy;
}
```

А теперь вопрос, как сделать так, чтобы при наведении на последний `div.p div.end` тоже окрашивался в `#yyy`?

Также можно вариатны реализации за счет JS

Решение найдено, можно закрывать, решение на PHP+JS+CSS

Comment: Выложи свое решение и прими его как ответ на вопрос.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Выборка следующего элемента осуществляется при помощи волшебного +а:

```
 .begin .p:hover + .end {
    /* применить правила при наведении на p, если следующий элемент имеет класс end */
 }
```

Не работает в IE <= 6.

Comment: Это именно то решение которое требовалось, спасибо, моя ошибка была в том что я делал div.p + .end:hover вместо div.p:hover + .end

спасибо

Comment: @capfsb - нет проблем. Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 0):

Может с помощью JS/JQUERY и onmouseover?
JS:

```
<div class="last" onmouseover="document.getElementById('end').style.background = '#yyy'" onmouseout="document.getElementById('end').style.background = '#xxx'">123</div>
<div id="end">END</div>
```

#xxx - это который был ДО наведения